# export p:datatable to excel in PrimeFaces

Tags: primefaces, datatable, export-to-csv

I want to export a datatable to excel.
I can not display the title of the datatable in excel.

```
<p:commandLink ajax="false">
  <h:outputLabel value="Excel"/>
    <p:dataExporter type="xls" 
         target="idColPlanCompteM61Export" 
         fileName="PlanCompteM61" 
         postProcessor="#{planCompteM61ManagerBean.postProcessXLS}"/>
</p:commandLink>

<p:dataTable id="idColPlanCompteM61Export" var="ligne" value="#{planCompteM61ManagerBean.listeColPlanCompteM61Filtree}">
            <f:facet name="header">
                   <div class="printTitrePosition">
                           <h:outputText value="Plan de compte M61"/>
                   </div>
            </f:facet>
            ...
            ...
```

No title is displayed

Comment: It might just not have been implemented.

Comment: you used `<h:form>`...`</h:form>`?

Comment: Yes I use : <h:form>...</h:form>

Answer (score 1):

Look at this example of DataExporter using Pre and Post Processor.

https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/dataexporter/customizedDocuments.xhtml

You want a postProcessor and you can manipulate the sheet and add your title in. Do it as a post processor and "Insert" a row at row 0 so POI will bump all the rows down and insert your new header row in row 0.